# Integrating java with R using renjin

Tags: java, r, spring-mvc, rpostgresql, renjin

I want to connect R to postgresql through Renjin for which I am using

```
engine.eval("library(RPostgreSQL)");
```

getting folllowing error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not load package RPostgreSQL; 
tried org.renjin.bioconductor:RPostgreSQL, org.renjin.cran:RPostgreSQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're embedding Renjin within a Java application or servlet, you'll need to make sure that RPostgreSQL is on the classpath, just like any other JAR.

You can find the maven coordinates of the RPostgreSQL library here:

http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/RPostgreSQL